# Series of if statements using in_array only works on last one

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a series of if statements to see if a values are in an array and, if so, change a variable.  The problem is that it only works on the last value found.

My code is:

```
    $accommodation_list = array();
    $ind_apt_query = array();
    $cottage_query = array();
    $asst_living_query = array();
    $skilled_care_query = array();
    $memory_loss_query = array(); 

if(isset($_GET['accommodations'])){
        $accommodation_values = implode(', ', $_GET['accommodations']);
        $accommodation_list = explode(" ", $accommodation_values);

        if( in_array('cottage_units', $accommodation_list) ){
            $cottage_query = array(
                'key' => 'rfp_cottage_units', 
                'value' => '', 
                'compare' => '!=',
            );
        }

        if( in_array('ind_apts', $accommodation_list) ){
            $ind_apt_query = array(
                'key' => 'rfp_ind_apt', 
                'value' => '', 
                'compare' => '!=',
            );
        }

        if( in_array('asst_living', $accommodation_list) ){
            $asst_living_query = array(
                'key' => 'rfp_assist_living_units', 
                'value' => '', 
                'compare' => '!=',
            );
        }

        if( in_array('skilled_care', $accommodation_list) ){
            $skilled_care_query = array(
                'key' => 'rfp_skilled_care_beds', 
                'value' => '', 
                'compare' => '!=',
            );
        }

        if( in_array('memory_loss', $accommodation_list) ){
            $memory_loss_query = array(
                'key' => 'rfp_memory_loss_units', 
                'value' => '', 
                'compare' => '!=',
            );
        }

    }
```

So if $accommodation_list = Array ( [0] => cottage_units, [1] => asst_living, [2] => memory_loss )  only the $memory_loss_query will be populated the others ($cottage_query and $asst_living_query) will still be empty.

How can I get this to work with all values in the array?

Comment: get rid of the explode/implode stuff at the beginning.

Comment: You're imploding on `<comma><space>` and then exploding the result on `<space>`, which means your array values are going to have commas in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're imploding on `<comma><space>` and then exploding the result on `<space>`, which means your array values are going to have commas in them:

```
(
    [0] => cottage_units,
    [1] => asst_living,
    [2] => memory_loss
)
```

So you end up comparing `asst_living` with `asst_living,` which obviously fails.

There's no need to destruct then rebuild the array, just check your `in_array()` call directly against the original array:

```
if (in_array('asst_living', $_GET['accommodations'])) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for being so quick.  You're solution worked perfectly!